# Users with their child count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Userid  Name ParentId
1        A     Null
2        B      1  
3        C      1
4        D      2 
5        E      3
```

so output should be like this:

```
UserId   Name  Childs
1         A     2       // A has two children B and C
2         B     1       // B has one child D
3         C     1       // C has one child E
```

So please help and let me know if any confusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.UserId, t1.Name, count(t2.UserId) 
FROM table t1 
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t2.parentid = t1.UserId 
GROUP BY t1.UserId, t1.Name
```

Comment: Nice query,just change `ON t2.parentid = t1.id` to `ON t2.parentid = t1.UserId` then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @test Table 
(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20),CID INT)
INSERT INTO @test 
VALUES
(1,  'A',NULL),
(2, 'B',1),
(3,  'C' ,1),
(1,  'D',2),
(2, 'E',3);

 ;WITH CTE AS
 ( 
select ID,Name from @test


  )
  select c.ID,c.Name,COUNT(t.ID) from CTE  C
  INNER JOIN @test t
  ON t.CID = c.ID
  GROUP by c.ID,c.Name
```